# Python Pandas: How to find in dataframe object type columns which has numeric data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the dataframe, I am trying to find numeric data columns which has dtype as "object". I want to do it automated way rather then looking into actual data within the dataframe.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
for obj_feature in df.select_dtypes(include="object").columns:
    if df[obj_feature].str.isalpha == False:
        print("Numeric data columns", obj_feature)
```

DDL to generate Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                  'A': ['Month', 'Year', 'Quater'],
                  'B' : ['29.85', '85.43', '33.87'],
                  'C' : [45, 22, 33.4]})
```

Sorry forgot to add this:
Expected Output: Pick Dataframe columns, B since it has numeric data values, but it has 'object' dtype.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not straight forward, the following is a wilcard and is all weather though

First select `dtypes='object'`
Second attempt to coerce them to numeric, setting `errors='coerce'`, what that will do is if alphanumeric, it will output them as `NaN` giving you the privilege to leverage `dropna()` and remain with only numeric/object `dtypes`

Code below

```
 df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')).dropna(axis=1)
```

Outcome

```
    B
0  29.85
1  85.43
2  33.87
```

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: Thanks @wwnde. This is what that I need as expected output.

Comment: What if I have NaN available in that column B. I suppose dropna(axis=1) will not work in that case. Am I right ?

Comment: I figure it out, then I will use this code: df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce')).dropna(axis=1, how='all')

Comment: Dropna (how='all', axis=1)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html):

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
{c: is_numeric_dtype(df[c]) for c in df}
```

output:

```
{'id': True, 'A': False, 'B': False, 'C': True}
```

#### selecting the numeric columns:

Here use [`select_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.select_dtypes('number')
```

output:

```
   id     C
0   1  45.0
1   2  22.0
2   3  33.4
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway for your answer, but I am expecting different output. Edited my question, Sorry I should have done that earlier.

Comment: not sure why I got downvoted, the question was clarified **after** I answered

Comment: I have not done that.

Comment: @Anku I didn't say it was you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html), consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                  'A': ['Month', 'Year', 'Quater'],
                  'B' : ['29.85', '85.43', '33.87'],
                  'C' : [45, 22, 33.4]})
for colname in df.columns:
    print(colname,pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df[colname]))
```

output

```
id True
A False
B False
C True
```

Comment: Thanks @Daweo for your answer, but I am expecting different output. Edited my question, Sorry I should have done that earlier.